# how to deploy only the Commit - continuous integration?

Tags: migration-tool, continuous-integration

I am facing an issue and am sure there must be very simple solution for this.Can anyone help me ?

I have bamboo server running which picks up stash rep where I have committed my code from Eclipse Force.com IDE. When I run the bamboo plan , it kind of deploys everything (all files from src) when I have committed only one component (say VF page). I modified mt package.xml to include only that VF page and nothing else. But still deployment runs across all 13k components.

I know I can remove all those components from my src folder and keep only VF page. SO that it deploys only that component. But is there any way , so that it picks up only the commit and not entire src folder ?

Any pointers helps greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you currently deal with your package.xml? That is where you decide which components to deploy. You've probably included all the files in your project in it now, but you could base it on a diff between the previous commit and your new commit.

Comment: Thanks for your reply  @KoenWesselman, I am right now considering way to generate package.xml automatically by differences. Doing it manually feels like I am in 17th century.

Comment: Haha, I know the feeling :-) have a look at my blogpost on automatic package.xml creation, it doesn't create a diff but may get you started with it: http://www.koenwesselman.com/automatic-package-xml-generation-salesforce/ - I'd be very interested in your solution (if you're willing to share it) when you get it working!